# login con Google mediante Firebase en una Progressive Web App

Tags: firebase, login, google-signin, pwa

Buenas, estoy haciendo una progressive web app con Firebase y React. Estoy usando el login de Google que proporciona Firebase, pero no acaba de funcionar correctamente. Cuango hago el login accediendo a la aplicación desde el navegador funciona correctamente, pero cuando accedo mediante el acceso directo creado en el móvil, al hacer el login con Google no funciona.
Con el método 

`const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
auth().signInWithPopup(provider);`
 lo que ocurre es que se redirecciona al login de Google pero cuando vuelve a la app no hay datos del usuario.
Usando el método 
`const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();

auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});`

lo que ocurre es que la app se cierra.
Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

yo estoy tratando de hacer lo mismo. 
Prueba con firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider); en lugar de ".signInWithPopup(provider)"

Saludos

Comment: Hola, tengo el mismo problema, y tampoco funciona con `signInWithRedirect`.. alguna sugerencia?